# using cross join but data doesn't appear

Tags: sql, mariadb, cross-join

A table

| idx | dy | mark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | ch |
| 2 | 7 | ox |

B table

| idx | name | d5 | d6 | d7 | d8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | star | NULL | ok | NULL | ok |

im using cross join to make relation B table to A table, but data can't appear..
my sql :

```
SELECT
A.name,
IFNULL(A.d5 IS NULL, CASE WHEN 5=B.dy THEN 'pr' END) AS `D5`
IFNULL(A.d6 IS NULL, CASE WHEN 6=B.dy THEN 'pr' END) AS `D6`
IFNULL(A.d7 IS NULL, CASE WHEN 7=B.dy THEN 'pr' END) AS `D7`
IFNULL(A.d8 IS NULL, CASE WHEN 8=B.dy THEN 'pr' END) AS `D8`
FROM
A,B
```

I hope to generate data like this:

|idx|name|D5|D6|D7|D8|
|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|
|1|star|pr|ok|pr|ok|

Comment: Will your case always =25 etc, do you need ELSE?  I think your aliases are for the wrong tables in the images too

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, thanks, for correction